# Is there any software to place free calls from a computer anymore?

Tags: software-rec, phone

I used to use IP-Relay because I worked for the company and it was convenient, if not a little weird to have someone translate your text into voice.  But that seems to not be as accessible as it used to be.
Is Skype free?  Is there anything else that's still free.  I'm sitting over at a friends house and I'd like to call him to tell him I'm at his house because he's supposed to meet me here and we're going to go see Avatar tonight, but I can't call him because I don't have a cell phone and he doesn't have a landline.  I'm not even sure if he has a microphone, but I don't have enough time to go digging only to find I have to pay for something any suggestions?  Quickly?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [iCall](http://www.icall.com/desktop/).

*You must call within the US or Canada to use it free.*

Comment: for only 5 mins...but a good one...also you can try voipbuster..